# How to get closure compiler to properly check the properties of a constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler

I can't understand how to get the google closure compiler for javascript to properly recognize properties of a constructor.    For example, in the code below, I don't know what type to give 'cls' in line 27 so that the compiler does NOT produce the following (erroneous in my opinion) error:

foo.js:29: WARNING - Property say never defined on cls
    cls.say();
    ^

From reading the documentation it seems that I should be doing it as I do in 25.  Can someone help please?  Thanks,

```
 1  /**
 2   * @interface
 3   **/
 4  function Sayer() {}
 5  Sayer.prototype.say = function() {};
 6  Sayer.say = function() {};
 7  
 8  /**
 9   * @constructor
10   * @implements {Sayer}
11   **/
12  function A() {}
13  A.say = function() { console.log('A factory'); };
14  A.prototype.say = function() { console.log('Am an A'); }
15  
16  /**
17   * @constructor
18   * @implements {Sayer}
19   **/
20  function B() {}
21  B.say = function() { console.log('B factory'); };
22  B.prototype.say = function() { console.log('Am an B'); };
23  
24  /**
25   * @param {function(new:Sayer)} cls
26   **/
27  function makeSayer(cls) {
28      var obj = new cls();
29      cls.say();
30      obj.say();
31  }
32  
33  makeSayer(A);
34  makeSayer(B);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change it to `new:B` or `new:A`?  I wonder if it doesn't handle interfaces well?  Or if interfaces aren't allowed to have static methods?

Comment: No difference.  I made Sayer a superclass of A and B, changed implements to extends, etc.  Still complains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sayer.say" on the interfaces is ignored.

Are you trying to prepare this for Closure's advanced mode?  In advanced mode "A.say" and "B.say" are renamed to "A$say" and "B$say", the type check expects this and complains about it appropriately (there won't be a method A.say).

You can avoid collapsing by have it added by it indirectly:

```
function addSay(sayer, fn) {
  sayer.say = fn;
}
```

I suppose you could avoid the type warning by adding a line like:

```
Function.prototype.say;
```

But I'm not sure you this is what you want.

You can avoid the hassle and add it to the prototype and call that instead:

```
A.prototype.classSay = function () {};
```

Comment: I have found out that the compiler does indeed not properly type check this.  The type warning won't go away (properly anyway) by creating a prototype declaration unless I really bastardize my code.  In any case, a bug report has been filed.  The real issue is that collapsing the "class" methods means the optimized code does NOT work properly if you want to pass in a class and have the called function create new instances of that class.  Alas.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the distinction between a method defined on a interface (`A.say`) vs a method defined on an interface's prototype (`A.prototype.say`). In Closure's type system the [`@interface` tag](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html#tag-interface) provides the following guarantee:

> Any class that implements an interface must implement all of the
>   methods and properties defined on the interface's prototype.

Notice it only cares about methods on the prototype. It doesn't care about methods on the interface itself.

Suppose you make a new class, `C`, that implements `Sayer`. Closure will make sure you define `C.prototype.say`. However you can skip `C.say`. You are not required to implement it. The following is a perfectly valid `Sayer`.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @implements {Sayer}
 */
function C() {}
C.prototype.say = function() { console.log('Am a C'); }
```

Since this is a valid `Sayer`, we should be safe to call `makeSayer(C)`. Now it is clear why your definition of `makeSayer` is incorrect. It assumes that `cls.say` is defined, but Closure makes no such guarantee. Closure spots the problem and gives you the appropriate error message.

So what should you do?

If you want to follow a standard object-oriented approach then you probably need two interfaces, one for the factory `SayerFactory` and one for the objects it creates `Say`. All of your methods will become methods defined in prototypes and Closure will do all your checking for you.

But if you like the idea of having a `say` method on your constructors then you could try using duck typing to enforce the presence of the factory method. Something like:

```
/**
 * @param {{say:function():Sayer}} cls
 */
function makeSayer(cls) {
  ...
}
```

Of course the duck typing approach won't scale very well if you need to define more than one method. The type signature would grow larger and larger for each method defined.

Good luck!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Thanks for that.